# what is the "===", and whats the big difference between it and the "=="

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

whats does the `===` mean when working with jquery/javascript? and whats the difference between `===` and `==`?

like i got this code

```
if ($this.val() != '' || ignore_empty === true) {
        var result = validateForm($this);

        if (result != 'skip') {
            if (validateForm($this)) {
                $input_container.removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            }
            else {
                $input_container.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            }
        }
    }
```

and there is the `===`

i just want to understand what it does and whats the difference.
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: @MagnusWinter hehe was just about to post that too... but tried to find the "possible duplicate of" thingie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equals operators. but `===` is type safe.

```
== This is the equal operator and returns a boolean true if both the 
   operands are equal.

=== This is the strict equal operator and only returns a Boolean true 
    if both the operands are equal and of the SAME TYPE.
```

for example:

```
3 == "3" (int == string) results in true

3 === "3" (int === string) results in false
```

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

== converts data to one type before comparing, === returns false if data of different types. === is preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

Loosely speaking, it provides stricter comparison.

```
"0" == 0 // true
"0" === 0 // false
```

For example...

For further info, I recommend following the link Magnus provided.